# minipage caption overrides

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, captions, minipage

I am using two mini pages side by side. The caption of both the figures are too long, that the caption of both the figures merges each other. I would like them to be separated by some space.[image]

*edited

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.97\linewidth]{a.eps}
\captionof{figure}{pectrogram of original speech signal (top), artificially bandlimited speech signal (middle), bandwidth extended speech (bottom)}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.97\linewidth]{b.eps}
\captionof{figure}{pectrogram of original speech signal (top), artificially bandlimited speech signal (middle), bandwidth extended speech (bottom)}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Any help would be appreciable

Comment: Could you please provide a complete MWE which is compilable and shows your issue? Like this, we have to guess around and type several lines of code for you. Thank you!

Comment: @Larifari, this code gives the issue i am facing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need `\captionof` here. Add a `\hfill` in between two `minipage`s.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
  %\centering
\begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.97\linewidth]{a}
\caption{\kant*[1]}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.97\linewidth]{b}
\caption{\kant*[1]}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Everyone for your comments. I tried Harish comments..It worked Perfectly... thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can make your minipages narrower and push them as far as possible (they are just separated by a word space in your posted code).

```
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.97\linewidth]{a.eps}
\captionof{figure}{caption as in image}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.97\linewidth]{b.eps}
\captionof{figure}{caption as  in image}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```